# How do I call a child batch file with arguments from parent batch file?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command, command-prompt

I have two batch files `PARENT.bat` and `CHILD.bat`

PARENT file script is

```
CALL CHILD.bat -username siva -password test1234
```

CHILD file job is to start the automation. We need to pass the arguments for `CHILD.bat`. For Example if we execute the `CHILD.bat` alone then we need to call like

```
CHILD.bat -username siva -password tet1234
```

but i want to pass the username and password values from PARENT.bat file to `CHILD.bat` batch process and it `CHILD.bat` process will start.

Can anyone please help the solution for this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling a batch file:

If the values you're passing are static, in the parent:

```
call "%batchfilepath%" username fred password 12za34xs
```

(Static passwords stored in batch files are by no means secure.)

If the values you're passing are dynamic (already stored in variables), in the parent:

```
call "%batchfilepath%" username "%userVar%" password "%passVar%"
```

**In the child, have a line to retrieve and assign those values:**

`Set "%~1=%~2" & Set "%~3=%~4"`

Comment: Thanks for your response @T3RR0R. It worked for me.

Comment: @tsivarajan Please accept (click the green checkmark) the answer if it worked, so you don't confuse people who are just coming to this question.

Answer (score -1):

I know that most would disagree with me, but I tend to solve problems like these with files.

You make two text files, `username.txt`, and `password.txt`, and the allow the parent to write to them, and the child to read from them, then delete the files when finished.

It would look something like this:

***PARENT***

```
echo siva > username.txt
echo test1234 > password.txt
start child.bat
```

***CHILD***

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (username.txt) DO set username=%%x
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (password.txt) DO set password=%%x
del username.txt
del password.txt
```

Very simple way to pass variables/parameters from one batch file to another, by saving them in files that will be automatically created and deleted.

Hope this helped.

Comment: I tried this approach. It's not working. I figured out the answer. Thanks for your time. I don't know why downvote and who gave it